# Create User Control is .Net without predictable ClientID Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, naming-conventions

I am creating a fieldset user control which makes it easier to use in my web application.

However, since it is a user control it needs a unique ID to create the control and the child controls inside of it

I have a ASP Placeholder control to allow the user control to accept child controls, but creates a longer and longer ClientID that isn't really necessary as this is standard .NET programming.

Is there a way to turn off this automatic referencing within the my user control and still retain the referencing in the parent object which the fieldset is in? (It is in a masterpage by the way...)

What I am asking is --- is there a way to create a usercontrol without the child elements of the usercontrol having their ID based on the parent usercontrol... I notice that the ASP UpdatePanel has this ability and want to replicate that same functionality.

Much appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to deal with this there is a good resource at [4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203215/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031710-1.aspx)

However in summary some of your options are :-

- The first is that you could make all your client id modes static - have a look at the [ClientIDMode in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Don't make predictable client id modes but use the Id of them in your code such as

  `var txt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxID.ClientID%>');`

  So here you would inject the client Id using ASP.NET directly into your HTML.
- Override the client ID to be static for each property - this is where you can specify in .NET what you want the client ID to be foreac control you are using.
  `<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I followed this webpage up but in practice it seems a little messy. 
I tried playing around with the ClientID and ClientIDMode, but nothing that fixes the problem with 'cleaner' ClientID. Plus, it appears the 'name' attribute doesn't appear to change at all in the HTML

Comment: If my naming container is 'm_c' and and has a fieldset user control of name 'f' the controls and textbox with ID of t then the full clientID for textbox should be 'm_c_t' the fieldset should be 'transparent'

Comment: Its one of the reasons I switched to the MVC system for full control over the client side of things. I found the web-forms model a bit cumbersome.